# Relative adverbs and commas

Tags: commas, relative-adverbs

I wonder why **in which** is put between 2 commas in this example.

> My main desire is a peaceful world, **in which**, there will be no war, no threat of terrorism.

Comment: It could just be a mistake or editing error. What's the source?

Comment: The commas are just to show you need to pause when reading the text. I think, as a learner, that colors the text with a more emphatic tone. However, I am not sure.

Comment: I wonder why too. Source? Really only one comma is needed. "My main desire is (for) a peaceful world, in which there will be no war and no threat of terrorism." You can put "nor" in place of "and no" if you want to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comma after "in which" is an error and should not be used in this sentence.

> My main desire is a peaceful world, in which there will be no war, no threat of terrorism.